# Delete parentheses around a text

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have a long file which contains texts and there is a particular type of text which is 24 character long (it can be lowercase alphabet or number),it starts and ends with " and there are parentheses around this.
One of these kind of row looks like this:

```
"something": ("qwertyuiopasdfghjklz1234"),
```

and I would like to get:

```
"something": "qwertyuiopasdfghjklz1234",
```

I would like to remove the parentheses. I have the following regex: `([a-z0-9"]{26})` which finds this expression but I don't seem to find a way to figure out what to write to replace the row in order to delete the parentheses.

Comment: You want `^\(("[a-z0-9]{24}")\)$` and replace with `$1`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fL5Ti8/1).

Comment: I think regex replace would apply for this. Regex expressions have additional parameters such as "flags" depending on the programing language that allows you to enable "multiline" and that would replace the text in the whole file. Would you be able to post a piece of the file?

Comment: It results in can't find the text ^\(("[a-z0-9]{24}")\)$

Comment: You seem to have 24 chars inside `("` and `")`. See `^\(("[a-z0-9]{24}")\)$`

Comment: I corrected that one based on your linked demo. Though, this one gives no occurance was found. I checked the length and it is 24 + the 2 " .

Comment: Please format the question and provide the exact sample line and expected output.

Comment: It is in the text. "something": ("qwertyuiopasdfghjklz1234"), ->"something": "qwertyuiopasdfghjklz1234",

Comment: But it does not meet your specs.

Comment: I think/taught that it can be done in that way as well.

Comment: The regex provided by @WiktorStribiżew is correct, you just need to remove the anchors to make it work with your data: https://regex101.com/r/fL5Ti8/2

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/fL5Ti8/3, `(:\h*)\(("[a-z0-9]{24}")\)(,)` => `$1$2$3`. Add `$` at the end of the regex if it appears at the end of a line.

Comment: Thanks, it works. If you provide an answer I accept it. Also, if you could give me a detailed break-down, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(:\h*)\(("[a-z0-9]{24}")\)(,)
```

Replace with `$1$2$3`, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fL5Ti8/3).

**Details**

- `(:\h*)` - Group 1 (`$1`): `:` and 0 or more horizontal whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `("[a-z0-9]{24}")` - Group 2 (`$2`): `"`, 24 lowercase ASCII letters or digits and then a `"`
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `(,)` - Group 3 (`$3`): a `,` char.

Answer (score 0):

You may use below code, working for your sample.
Find what: `\(|\)`
Replace with: `nothing`